# js for loop sort numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, for-loop

I have a form where I want people to put in their year of birth. You can only apply if you are over 18 so in the year of birth field I want the min age to be 18.  I have done this as shown below however I want to sort the numbers from latest year at the top and oldest year at the bottom. currently I show 1913 first, but I want to show 1994 first.  Here is my code

```
<div id="my-container"></div>

<script>
      var d = new Date();
      var y = d.getFullYear();
      var selectList = "<select>";
      for (var x = (y-100); x < (y - 18); x++) {
          selectList += "<option>" + x + "</option>";
      }
      selectList += "</select>";
      $('#my-container').html(selectList);
      </script>
```

Comment: Switch the `(y-100)`, `(y-18)`, `<` sign, and `++` operator... For more information, look up for loops.

Comment: yes I tried something like that, but i didn't have the syntax right, I probably should have added this to the question. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Nile mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126798/js-for-loop-sort-numbers/15126843#comment21290540_15126798),

```
var d = new Date();
var y = d.getFullYear();
var selectList = "<select>";
for (var x = y-18; x >= y-100; x--) {
    selectList += "<option>" + x + "</option>";
}
selectList += "</select>";
$('#my-container').html(selectList);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/WzwKw/

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 <script>
  var d = new Date();
  var y = d.getFullYear();
  var selectList = "<select>";
  for (var x = y-18; x > y - 100; x--) {
      selectList += "<option>" + x + "</option>";
  }
  selectList += "</select>";
  $('#my-container').html(selectList);
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready( function() {
    var d = new Date();
    var y = d.getFullYear();
    var selectList = "<select>";
    for (var x = (y-18); x >= (y - 100); x--) {
      selectList += "<option>" + x + "</option>";
    }
    selectList += "</select>";
    $('#my-container').html(selectList);
    });
</script>
```

Please try with this.